Material table slows after several data changes
So, I have fetchData() function that updates data everytime I clicked next or previous page button (basically, every page change). Here's the snippet
const fetchData = (limit, offset) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const body = {
        ...(keyword ? { keyword } : {}),
        limit,
        offset,
        minify: true,
    };

    axiosUtil
        .request("POST", body.keyword ? "/blocker/private/user/popup-search" : "/blocker/private/user/popup-all", body, token)
        .then((data) => {
            const result = data.data ?? data;

            let startTime = performance.now();
            console.log("Mapping data...");
            const mapped = result.map((e) => {
                let color = "#36AE7C";
                let text = "Enable Popup";
                let icon = "CheckCircleOutlineIcon";
                if (e.is_disabled != true) {
                    color = "#E23E57";
                    text = "Disabled Popup";
                    icon = "CancelIcon";
                }

                if (e.interval) {
                    e.type = <Chip label="Repeating Response" color="secondary" />;
                } else {
                    e.type = <Chip label="Single Response" color="primary" />;
                }

                e.color = color;
                e.icon = icon;
                e.text = text;

                e.filter_parent = Object.keys(e.filter).toString().replace(/,/g, ", ");
                e.date = moment(e.createdAt).format("D MMMM YYYY");
                e.action = (
                    <>
                        <ButtonGroup variant="contained" color="primary" size="small">
                            <Tooltip title="View Detail">
                                <IconButton color="primary" onClick={() => handleOpen(e.id)}>
                                    <VisibilityIcon />
                                </IconButton>
                            </Tooltip>
                            <Tooltip title={e.text}>
                                <IconButton style={{ color: e.color }} onClick={() => handleDisable(e.id, e.is_disabled)}>
                                    <PowerSettingsNewIcon />
                                </IconButton>
                            </Tooltip>
                            <Tooltip title="View Response">
                                <IconButton style={{ color: "#4D77FF" }} onClick={() => handleResponse(e.id, e.title, e.interval)}>
                                    <ListAltIcon />
                                </IconButton>
                            </Tooltip>
                            <Tooltip title="Remove message">
                                <IconButton style={{ color: "#E23E57" }} onClick={() => handleRemove(e.id)}>
                                    <DeleteOutline />
                                </IconButton>
                            </Tooltip>
                        </ButtonGroup>
                    </>
                );
                return e;
            });
            let endTime = performance.now();
            let executionTime = endTime - startTime; // in milliseconds with higher precision
            console.log(`Execution time: ${executionTime.toFixed(3)} ms`);

            startTime = performance.now();
            console.log("Setting data...");
            fetchCountPopup();
            unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
                setData(mapped);
            });
            endTime = performance.now();
            executionTime = endTime - startTime; // in milliseconds with higher precision
            console.log(`Execution time: ${executionTime.toFixed(3)} ms`);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            logout();
        });
};

I've logged the execution time and found out that the mapping operation is not the problem and setData() function takes more time after changing the page several time

Then I commented data={data} on my MaterialTable component and the spike on setData()'s execution time is gone
<MaterialTable
    className={classes.root}
    icons={tableIcons}
    title="Released Popup"
    columns={columns}
    style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
    data={data}
    options={{
        search: false,
    }}
    components={{
        Pagination: (props) => (
            <TablePagination
                {...props}
                rowsPerPage={numberRowPerPage}
                count={totalPopup}
                page={pageNumber - 1}
                onChangePage={(e, page) => handleChangePage(page + 1)}
                onChangeRowsPerPage={(event) => {
                    props.onChangeRowsPerPage(event);
                    handleChangeRowPerPage(event.target.value);
                }}
            />
        ),
    }}
/>

And there's also spike on memory usage

My conclusion is it caused by the MaterialTable rerendering. How do I fix that? I'm using "material-table": "^1.68.1"

Solved by hardcoding columns into MaterialTable component directly since there is a memory leak bug for dynamic columns.
<MaterialTable
    ...
    columns={[
        { title: "Title", field: "title" },
        { title: "Filter", field: "filter_parent" },
        { title: "Type", field: "type" },
        { title: "Created by", field: "created_by" },
        { title: "Created at", field: "date" },
        { title: "Action", field: "action" },
    ]}
    style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
    data={data}
    options={{
        search: false,
    }}
    ...
/>

instead of
<MaterialTable
    ...
    columns={columns}
    style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
    data={data}
    options={{
        search: false,
    }}
    ...
/>

